# wxPython - AnimationCtrl with Gif results in Kernel Crash

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, wxpython, gif

I use this piece of Code trying to display and animate a Gif inside my GUI. But if i run this, my Kernel dies instantly.

What did i do wrong?

Here is my Code:

```
import wx
from wx.adv import Animation, AnimationCtrl

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        gif_fname = wx.adv.Animation("Test.gif")
        gif = wx.adv.AnimationCtrl(parent=self,anim=gif_fname)
        gif.GetAnimation()

        self.gif = gif

        self.gif.Play()

        sizer.Add(gif)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test=wx.App()
    TestPanel(None)
    test.MainLoop()
```